# How do I receive and read a POST HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to send a post request from a file to a website, then on the website console log the recived data. (From the post request). Heres what im trying to send

`let data = "'<Website Href>'"`

Originaly I tried just accesing the vairable thinking if it was recieved I would not need any extra code but that didnt work.

So how do I recieve then console log the Post request data? (I already know how to send a request just not read it)

Comment: You need a backend. The Javascript on page is client-side code and isn't responsible for receiving requests like that. You need to find something like Node.js, ASP.NET etc to create a backend for your site

Answer (score 2):

A client-side script on web page can't read body data sent in a POST request. It *can* read data included on the URL querystring from a GET request though (e.g. it could read the `123` value from `https://example.com/page.html?id=123`).

Example:

```
var url = new URL(location.href);
var x = url.searchParams.get("id");
console.log(x);
```

If you need or want to work with POST requests, then as mentioned in the comments you'll need a server-side language. Choices are plentiful, including ASP.NET/C#, NodeJS, PHP, python, Perl, Java, and probably more.